# C++ MPI: Kill Slaves

Tags: c++, mpi

I'm developing a c++ application using MPI.
I separate the tasks between slaves.

But, some slave can complete the main task successfully, and I want that the slave warns the master, and the master kill the other slaves.
That's possible?

I read about MPI_Abort, but I think this is useful just for exceptions.

Thanks!

Comment: This was already discussed in [that question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10490983/mpi-slave-processes-receive-until-root-exits/).

Answer (score 2):

The slaves would have to periodically check if they need to exit.  One way to do this is to have every slave call `MPI_Irecv` with a special "kill tag", and periodically `MPI_Test` for completion.  Once the master wants the slaves to exit, it issues the matching `MPI_Send`s.